# Center sideways text in table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating

I'm trying to make a two-column table environment. The left column is supposed to center the  sideways text "Tips" vertically and the right column should be a normal paragraph column.
Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{rotating} % for sideways
\usepackage{array}    % for the m centering

\newenvironment{tips}
{
    \begin{tabular}{m{5mm}|p{0.9\textwidth}}
    \begin{sideways} \textbf{Tips} \end{sideways} &
}
{\end{tabular}}
```

I have tried both m and c, but the left column text is still at the top.
[image]

This also gives me the problem that for longer texts in the left column, the vertical space before the table becomes larger.
Any help?

Also, a quick second question: Is there a unit which makes the second column "fill out" the remainder of the page horizontally? I'm missing out a couple of millimeters using 0.9*\textwidth.

Comment: Please add the preamble that is needed to make this code work.

Comment: Added it now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using the `sideways` environment, I would suggest using a `\rotatebox{90}{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newenvironment{tips}
{
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{m{0.03\textwidth}|m{0.97\textwidth}}
\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Tips!}}&
}
{\end{tabular}
\bigskip
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tips}
Short Tip
\end{tips}

\begin{tips}
Forsok att undvika mer an fyra nastlade nivaer. Senare kapitel kommer ge dig forslag pa hur du kan strukturera om koden sa att du slipper onodig nastling. Forsok att undvika mer an fyra nastlade nivaer. Senare kapitel kommer ge dig forslag pa hur du kan strukturera om koden sa att du slipper onodig. nastling
\end{tips}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I presume the `tikz` is a mistake...

Comment: Quick follow-up question: The right column now ignores my paragraph spacing (empty line after each paragraph). How do I get this back? Setting it to p gives me the original error.

Comment: @pg-robban: How did you define that paragraph spacing? Could you edit your question to make a complete minimal example document?

Comment: I'm using `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` at the beginning of the document.

Comment: @pg-robban: Using `parskip` doesn't have any influence on the paragraph spacing inside the `tabular` for me, regardless of the cell type used. It would be good if you could create a minimal example document.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MyZdvWHF

gives me http://i.imgur.com/6CDCJ.png

Edit: My text says indent. I mean the paragraph spacing.

Comment: @pg-robban: I get the same result. But if I use your original definition of the `tips` environment, the paragraph spacing in the right column is the same, so it doesn't have anything to do with the `p` or `m` cell type.

Comment: How could I centralize the whole thing?